# Scenekit SCNShadable texture2D not working

Tags: opengl, scenekit, metal

I have some code like this:

```
let myShader = 
    "#pragma arguments\n" +
    "sampler uMaskTex;\n" +
    "uniform sampler2D uMaskTex;\n" +

    "#pragma body\n" +

    //none of these work
    "vec3 mask = texture2D( uMaskTex , vec2(1.,1.) ).xyz;\n" +
    //"vec3 mask = texture2d( uMaskTex , vec2(1.,1.) ).xyz;\n" +
    //"vec3 mask = texture( uMaskTex , vec2(1.,1.) ).xyz;\n" +
    "_output.color.rgb = vec3(1.);"
```

I get a pink mesh. If i comment out the texture2D lines the shader works. I get no errors in the console. The uniforms don't break it either so i assume they are working (although im really confused as to why i need two of them, one for opengl the other for metal).

What is the proper way of reading a uniform sampler2D from a shader with this SCNShadable mechanism?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `metal`? Are you using Metal in some fashion?

Comment: because if i understand glsl gets transpiled to whatever metal's shading language is. I know i had some issues with global functions similar to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762535/scenekit-shader-modifier-for-geometry-entry-points-works-in-ios-but-not-os-x

I'm using PBR and it seems to be working with metal exclusively (been getting some warnings along those lines). You tell me, should it be tagged metal or not? The documentation says to declare two uniforms, one for metal one for GLSL even though i might be writing just GLSL. Am i using metal or not?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not trying to be mean or anything, but given the answer below did this make it more or less a metal issue? I'm really curious, mostly because im frustrated with scenekit and it's documentation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the shader cross-compiler's whitespace sensitivity. Specifically, if I change

```
vec3 mask = texture2D( uMaskTex , vec2(1.,1.) ).xyz;
```

to

```
vec3 mask = texture2D( uMaskTex, vec2(1.,1.) ).xyz;
```

(note the absence of a space after the first parameter), it seems to work.

It's probably worth [filing a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) for this. The parser should discard that whitespace instead of treating it as part of the identifier.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out. Any advice on how to get the shader to throw an error?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In order to debug this, I set a symbolic breakpoint on `newLibrary:options:error:` and then printed the source string with `po $arg3`. From there, I tried compiling the generated string as a `.metal` file in Xcode, tweaking the preprocessor directives until it hit the compilation error that caused your code to fail (the generated sampler was named `uMaskTex Sampler` rather than `uMaskTexSampler`. It was simple deduction to then realize that the parser thought that extra space was part of the sampler name.

Comment: Holy $%^$#^! Hats off, that sounds insane, seems like quite a bit of work!

Comment: I am now getting a white diffuse color even if i don't touch the last line. Reading the "mask" texture correctly multiplies it over white ( i believe it still gets some shading from PBR but it's acting as if the diffuse is set to white not black as i have it). 

Commenting out the last line, and leaving just the texture fetch into a variable that never gets used anywhere still paints the object white. Any ideas? Next beer at Willows is on me.

Comment: Posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855337/scenekit-scnshadable-accessing-surface-diffusetexcoord-paints-the-object-white